# node outside catkin workspace

Tags: ros, catkin, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

I have a complex application in which I would like to integrate ROS, so as to make a ros node out of it an be able to send messages, call services...

This application is complex and heavy and would not fit well in a catkin workspace (a silly refactoring would be needed). Actually ROS is not very central in this specific application and thus integrating ROS should not require a heavy reorganisation (such as putting the codebase in a catkin workspace).

Is there a way to integrate ROS in an application outside of the catkin workspace? I guess most complex software willing to integrate ROS have the same issue...

Thanks,

Antoine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217773/node-outside-catkin-workspace/) by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2015-09-16

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2015-09-17**:
Interesting... Can I generate the custom messages in a separate package inside catkin and use the generated msg from my complex application?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-09-17**:
Probably yes. Putting messages into a separate package is the recommended practice, anyway. http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_msgs.html .

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-09-17**:
(moved to answer)

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-09-17**:
I converted my comments to an answer.

**Comment by [babu](https://answers.ros.org/users/29471/babu/) on 2017-03-13**:
@arennuit can you please provide a sample listener which is outside of catkin workspace ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If it is a CMake project you can just `find_package(roscpp REQUIRED)`, `find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)`, and so on. Then use the resulting `_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `_LIBRARIES` CMake variables to integrate it into your project. You'll start to have issues when you want to generate custom messages.

From @arennuit

> Interesting... Can I generate the custom messages in a separate package inside catkin and use the generated msg from my complex application?

Sure. The reason the messages need to be generated within a catkin package is that the fully qualified name of messages includes the package they are from. Other than message, service, action, and dynamic reconfigure generation, the rest (I think) can be done outside of a catkin package.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3